# How to deeper debug Apache 500 interal server errors with owncloud

Tags: php, apache, webdav, owncloud, sabredav

I have internal server errors with my owncloud installation for each PUT or DELETE request WebDAV (sabre/dav). See my access.log excerpt:

```
192.168.2.11 - - [14/Mar/2015:08:39:44 +0100] "PROPFIND /remote.php/webdav HTTP/1.1" 207 5272
192.168.2.11 - - [14/Mar/2015:08:39:44 +0100] "DELETE /remote.php/webdav/Documents/MyDocument.rtf HTTP/1.1" 500 529
192.168.2.11 - - [14/Mar/2015:08:39:45 +0100] "DELETE /remote.php/webdav/Documents/AnotherDoc.doc HTTP/1.1" 500 529
192.168.2.11 - - [14/Mar/2015:08:39:45 +0100] "PUT /remote.php/webdav/Documents/TEST1.TXT HTTP/1.1" 500 529
192.168.2.11 - - [14/Mar/2015:08:39:45 +0100] "PUT /remote.php/webdav/Documents/TEST2.TXT HTTP/1.1" 500 529
192.168.2.11 - - [14/Mar/2015:08:40:12 +0100] "PROPFIND /remote.php/webdav/ HTTP/1.1" 207 502
192.168.2.11 - - [14/Mar/2015:08:40:23 +0100] "PROPFIND /remote.php/webdav/ HTTP/1.1" 207 1270
```

At the same time I can find this in Apaches error.log:

```
[Sat Mar 14 08:39:45.350992 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 16840:tid 880] (OS 109)Die Pipe wurde beendet.  : [client 192.168.2.11:53446] mod_fcgid: get overlap result error
[Sat Mar 14 08:39:45.350992 2015] [core:error] [pid 16840:tid 880] [client 192.168.2.11:53446] End of script output before headers: remote.php
[Sat Mar 14 08:39:45.803398 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 16840:tid 880] (OS 109)Die Pipe wurde beendet.  : [client 192.168.2.11:53447] mod_fcgid: get overlap result error
[Sat Mar 14 08:39:45.803398 2015] [core:error] [pid 16840:tid 880] [client 192.168.2.11:53447] End of script output before headers: remote.php
```

Also same time owncloud.log has some more details:

```
{"reqId":"45d62f7c8057519037a1480b67a1c2de","remoteAddr":"192.168.2.11","app":"user_ldap","message":"No group filter is specified, LDAP group feature will not be used.","level":1,"time":"2015-03-14T07:39:46+00:00","method":"PUT","url":"\/remote.php\/webdav\/Documents\/TEST2.TXT"}
{"reqId":"45d62f7c8057519037a1480b67a1c2de","remoteAddr":"192.168.2.11","app":"lock","message":"INFO: Write lock requested for F:\/Apache\/owncloud\/Apache24\/htdocs\/data\/testuser\/files\/documents\/test2.txt.octransferid18718.part","level":0,"time":"2015-03-14T07:39:46+00:00","method":"PUT","url":"\/remote.php\/webdav\/Documents\/TEST2.TXT"}
{"reqId":"45d62f7c8057519037a1480b67a1c2de","remoteAddr":"192.168.2.11","app":"lock","message":"PASS: Write lock succeeded on F:\/Apache\/owncloud\/Apache24\/htdocs\/data\/testuser\/files\/documents\/test2.txt.octransferid18718.part","level":0,"time":"2015-03-14T07:39:46+00:00","method":"PUT","url":"\/remote.php\/webdav\/Documents\/TEST2.TXT"}
{"reqId":"45d62f7c8057519037a1480b67a1c2de","remoteAddr":"192.168.2.11","app":"lock","message":"INFO: Incrementing lock type 2 count for F:\/Apache\/owncloud\/Apache24\/htdocs\/data\/testuser\/files\/documents\/test2.txt.octransferid18718.part","level":0,"time":"2015-03-14T07:39:46+00:00","method":"PUT","url":"\/remote.php\/webdav\/Documents\/TEST2.TXT"}
{"reqId":"45d62f7c8057519037a1480b67a1c2de","remoteAddr":"192.168.2.11","app":"lock","message":"INFO: Read lock requested for F:\/Apache\/owncloud\/Apache24\/htdocs\/data\/testuser\/files\/documents\/test2.txt.octransferid18718.part","level":0,"time":"2015-03-14T07:39:47+00:00","method":"PUT","url":"\/remote.php\/webdav\/Documents\/TEST2.TXT"}
{"reqId":"45d62f7c8057519037a1480b67a1c2de","remoteAddr":"192.168.2.11","app":"lock","message":"PASS: Acquired read lock for F:\/Apache\/owncloud\/Apache24\/htdocs\/data\/testuser\/files\/documents\/test2.txt.octransferid18718.part","level":0,"time":"2015-03-14T07:39:47+00:00","method":"PUT","url":"\/remote.php\/webdav\/Documents\/TEST2.TXT"}
{"reqId":"45d62f7c8057519037a1480b67a1c2de","remoteAddr":"192.168.2.11","app":"lock","message":"INFO: Incrementing lock type 1 count for F:\/Apache\/owncloud\/Apache24\/htdocs\/data\/testuser\/files\/documents\/test2.txt.octransferid18718.part","level":0,"time":"2015-03-14T07:39:47+00:00","method":"PUT","url":"\/remote.php\/webdav\/Documents\/TEST2.TXT"}
{"reqId":"45d62f7c8057519037a1480b67a1c2de","remoteAddr":"192.168.2.11","app":"lock","message":"INFO: Write lock requested for F:\/Apache\/owncloud\/Apache24\/htdocs\/data\/testuser\/files\/documents\/test2.txt","level":0,"time":"2015-03-14T07:39:47+00:00","method":"PUT","url":"\/remote.php\/webdav\/Documents\/TEST2.TXT"}
{"reqId":"45d62f7c8057519037a1480b67a1c2de","remoteAddr":"192.168.2.11","app":"lock","message":"PASS: Write lock succeeded on F:\/Apache\/owncloud\/Apache24\/htdocs\/data\/testuser\/files\/documents\/test2.txt","level":0,"time":"2015-03-14T07:39:47+00:00","method":"PUT","url":"\/remote.php\/webdav\/Documents\/TEST2.TXT"}
{"reqId":"45d62f7c8057519037a1480b67a1c2de","remoteAddr":"192.168.2.11","app":"lock","message":"INFO: Incrementing lock type 2 count for F:\/Apache\/owncloud\/Apache24\/htdocs\/data\/testuser\/files\/documents\/test2.txt","level":0,"time":"2015-03-14T07:39:47+00:00","method":"PUT","url":"\/remote.php\/webdav\/Documents\/TEST2.TXT"}
{"reqId":"45d62f7c8057519037a1480b67a1c2de","remoteAddr":"192.168.2.11","app":"PHP","message":"unlink(F:\\Apache\\owncloud\\Apache24\\htdocs\\data\/testuser\/files\/documents\/test2.txt): Permission denied at F:\\Apache\\owncloud\\Apache24\\htdocs\\lib\\private\\files\\storage\\mappedlocal.php#270","level":3,"time":"2015-03-14T07:39:47+00:00","method":"PUT","url":"\/remote.php\/webdav\/Documents\/TEST2.TXT"}
{"reqId":"d8898b5d419ba2468cf5021413104369","remoteAddr":"192.168.2.11","app":"lock","message":"INFO: Read lock requested for F:\/Apache\/owncloud\/Apache24\/htdocs\/data\/testuser\/files\/documents\/test2.txt","level":0,"time":"2015-03-14T07:40:28+00:00","method":"GET","url":"\/remote.php\/webdav\/Documents\/TEST2.TXT"}
{"reqId":"d8898b5d419ba2468cf5021413104369","remoteAddr":"192.168.2.11","app":"lock","message":"PASS: Acquired read lock for F:\/Apache\/owncloud\/Apache24\/htdocs\/data\/testuser\/files\/documents\/test2.txt","level":0,"time":"2015-03-14T07:40:28+00:00","method":"GET","url":"\/remote.php\/webdav\/Documents\/TEST2.TXT"}
{"reqId":"d8898b5d419ba2468cf5021413104369","remoteAddr":"192.168.2.11","app":"lock","message":"INFO: Incrementing lock type 1 count for F:\/Apache\/owncloud\/Apache24\/htdocs\/data\/testuser\/files\/documents\/test2.txt","level":0,"time":"2015-03-14T07:40:28+00:00","method":"GET","url":"\/remote.php\/webdav\/Documents\/TEST2.TXT"}
```

Based on owncloud.log it looks like it is a "access denied" problem (at least for the unlink message), however, the related Apache User has full permissions, and I monitored the progress with Sysinternals Process-Monitor, it has not one Access Denied error, just Success, and not found. See screenshot:

http://bilder.ath.cx/temp/Proccess-Monitor.png

To ensure it's no a permission issue, I tried also to run Apache as local Administrtor, which has the same effect.

My setup is: Windows 2k8 R2 with Owncloud 8.0.0.7, Apache 2.4.12 and PHP 5.6.5

I'm really lost how I could get this solved out, has anyone a tip what I could try next?

Help is much appreciated.

LC

Comment: I suggest you open an issue in ownClouds github repositories concerning this. It is unlikely that you will get an answer here. Especially since running ownCloud on a MS-Windows platform is not exactly common...

Comment: I know, that's why I just would like to know here what else I could do to debug the 500 errors. In the Owncloud forum support is very limited :(

Comment: Not talking about a forum. I suggested to open an issue in their repository: https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues

Comment: OK I did raise it there: https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/14894

Comment: Great to see things are already confusing. So asking the owncloud community _does_ help :-)